# Call SEL(selector) of a class in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, selector

I have a class in which i am calling a method(with a SEL parameter) of another class like as follows

```
// class 1

+(CCScene *) scene
{
// 'scene' is an autorelease object.
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

// 'layer' is an autorelease object.
HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];

// add layer as a child to scene 
[scene addChild: layer];

// returns a CClayer Object
id myClassLayer = [myClass objWithBackgroundSprite:objBackground withRect:CGRectMake(160,100, 300,120) atPoistion:pos_Top];

SEL callOnClick;
[myClassLayer AddButtonWithImage:ButtonBackground selector:callOnClick withDisabledImage:disabledBackground];

[scene addChild: myClassLayer];

// return the scene
return scene;
}

// class 2

-(void)AddButtonToHUDWithImage:(NSString *)imageName selector:(SEL)selector withDisabledImage:(NSString *)disbdImageName

{

CCMenuItem *menuItem1 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:imageName selectedImage:imageName disabledImage:disbdImageName target:self selector:@selector(selector)];

CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuItem1,nil];  
[menu setPosition:ccp(160,100)];
[self addChild:menu];
}

-(void)selector
{
    // not creating any object .. some other way if possible
}
```

but i would like to declare the selector method(callOnClick) in HelloWorld only(myClass being a Generic Class).

How can i call the selector in HelloWorld only??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need no instance, then you can use a class method and the target/object will be `[SOMEType class]` or `[self class]`:

```
+ (void)selector // <<    + not -
{
    // not creating any object .. some other way if possible
}
```